# reload/update page javascript

Tags: reload, setinterval

I think that my question is actually very simple and I thought the answer was somewhere hidden in some related questions. But I couldn't get my code to work, so here is my problem:

I need to read a file that is non-periodically chanced and do really nice stuffs with the data in it. So far, I've been doing this "locally" (this file will be on a server later) and it works just fine. Just for testing to see if the data was being read correctly, the changes on the file were done by me and I just hit F5 on the browser to get the "new page". All this is fine!

The thing is, I need the webpage to reload itself only when the file was changed. So I read the file, check if update!= lastupdate to reload the page. The problem is that it doesn't matter if the condition is true or false the page always reloads!! not cool! This is one of the approaches I've done so far:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('object.json', function(data) {
        if ( data.update != lastUpdate ){                   
            lastUpdate = data.update;
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}, 2000);
```

This functions checks every 2 seconds if the file was changed and then if true reload the page. But it reloads every 2 seconds instead of each time the file is changed ... Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks and regards, 
Julls

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a closing curly brace?

```
       setInterval(function() {
            $.getJSON('object.json', function(data) {
                if ( data.update != lastUpdate ){                   
                    lastUpdate = data.update;
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but that wasn't the problem :S I just deleted some comments on the post and took with it the closing thing xD ... do you have any other ideas? :)

Comment: If window.location.reload(); is firing then data.update must not equal lastUpdate. Replace "data.update != lastUpdate" with "1 != 1" to prove to yourself that the page will not refresh if they are the same and then either use alert boxes or javascript console in chrome / safari or firebug in firefox to have a look at the values of data.update and lastUpdate at run time. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, didn't see your answer yesterday sorry. I figured out the problem. Each time the page reloads lastUpdate refreshes too, so the line lastUpdate = data.update is actually useless! I tried not reloading the page, but calling again the function that reads the object and actually does something with the data. That doesn't work because somehow the page looses all the interaction it is supposed to have. Any ideas why? or maybe I could write in the file lastUpdate = update and then read both things and if update changes, write lastupdate = update again ... ?

Comment: Sorry you have lost me now.  When the page loads set the value of last update to the value that was used in the file. If you update the page using AJAX remember to update the lastUpdate variable. This way whether the page refreshes or not, lastUpdate will always be correct.

Comment: I read the json file and play with it once. I have a setInterval function to read the same file and only check if it was changed (by reading "update"). If it was change I'd like to see the changes that were done. For that I thought of reloading the page location.reload(). How do I update/reload the page using AJAX?

Comment: AJAX isn't needed, page refresh can work also. If it was AJAX, javascript/ jquery would update the DOM like: $('.#result').html(result);

Comment: Hi max, im sry if im being too noob here but I can't use refresh like this because lastUpdate will refresh itself too. That means that data.update != lastUpdate will always be true and the page wil always refreshes itself every 2 seconds, which is exactly whats happening. I dont understand your tip with $('.#result').html(result); ... could you explain that please? thanks xD

Comment: I don't think I can explain in any more detail, best of luck!